# Canvas .toDataURL() returns partially corrupted image

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

We have a web application that (very intermittently) is returning a partially corrupted PNG image data URL. The image has a large black section covering *some* of the image but not all of it. These images are customer signatures.
  For example:

[image]

We are using the signature pad component from [this](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad). The image URL is returned using the `getSignatureImage()` routine.

The only thing I have seen from the access logs seems to show the affected requests coming from "Samsung Galaxy Tab" devices, but using Chrome 59. However other requests from the same devices work OK.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Somehow, I guess it depends on the memory of the device. Can you reproduce it in any ways?

Comment: What is the size of the PNG image file? Also, can this image be viewed without issues from a browser or other applications with capabilities to display an image?

Comment: Hi all, looks like this may be device dependent (memory related).  The end user is trying a device swap to see if this resolves the issue.  To answer the questions... no I cannot reproduce this and yes, the signature image looks fine when displayed on the browser screen before it is saved to the JSON from transmission back to the application server.

Comment: Do you know if the signature is ok in the offscreen buffer?

Comment: And just out of curiousity, could you test what happens if you replace the [fillRect](https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad/blob/gh-pages/jquery.signaturepad.js#L803) call with clearRect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now confirmed that the issue was device dependant.

The end users affected have changed from older `Samsung Galaxy Tab 4` devices to `Tab S2` devices.  The problem no longer occurs.

It appears to have been a string length limitation on the older devices.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a memory issue. When image consumes too much memory, an image will by simply black (empty pixels *rgb(0,0,0)*).
Try to get blob from canvas - canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {}).
Probably your image not loaded or draw yet. Try to put *window.setTimeout* somewhere before you get the image data (base64 or blob)